# STM32F4 Discovery GPIO signal generation problem

Tags: digital-logic, stm32, gpio

I'm trying to generate a signal to interface with a Nintendo 64 controller using my STM32F4-DISC1 (STM32F429). The signal I'm trying to generate for now is just 1us high followed by 1us low (repeat ad infinitum).

There are two problems I'm facing:

1. I can't seem to get the correct timing working. The main clock should be 180 MHz (as reported by the "get clocks" function, sorry forgot the full name). This should mean there are 180 cycles per microsecond, right? But when I set the GPIO to high, wait for 180 cycles (180 nops) and then set it to low again, 3.5us have passed. What am I missing here?
2. The signal I'm generating using the code below works well after a time, but not at first. If I look at it with a logic analyzer, then the first capture will always look like this:

   [image: logic analyzer capture, first try]

   As you can see above, the signal is high only for a very short time (about 0.17us). Without modifying the code though, just by capturing again, the signal changes to this:

   [image: logic analyzer capture, later]

   In both cases, the code hasn't changed and waits for 180 cycles. If relevant, I'm using the Open Bench Logic Analyzer at 200 MHz sampling frequency.

### Initialization code

[image]

### Signal generation code

[image: Signal generation code]

**Note: `0xE0001004` is the address of the cycle counter, which is updated automatically. So there's no need to modify `r6` in the wait loop.**

Also note that I've tried the waiting using different techniques, including just using 180 NOPs. This had mostly the same outcome.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this with a timer and implementing a PWM? This will give you an accurate waveform that will run ad infinitum once the timer is set up correctly.

Comment: Probably because I've never done anything like this before, and this is the approach I was able to come up with. I'll see what I can dig up on PWM :)

Comment: Have you considered that running on 180 MHz you will have wait states when the instructions are fetched from the flash? Or is the code running from RAM?

Comment: Fair enough. :) Definitely worth learning about for this application.

Answer (score 4):

This was going to be a comment, but then I realized that I need to write more than a comment window allows. So this will be 50% comment and 10% answer and 40% unknown.

I'm pretty familiar with asm on AVR and on PIC and how many cycles each instruction takes. So I can make educated guesses regarding how your asm program will behave.

The fact that you even get 3.5 µs periods is strange by the look of your code.

---

**Here's a couple of things that I can't wrap my head around:**

- You are not 100% sure that #0xe0001000 even is *DWT BASE*, why are you not sure? Isn't that something... you should... be sure of?
- You want to wait 180 cycles, yet every time you loop in your *wait* loop, you execute 6 instructions, 4 of which I think are 1 cycle per instruction. And the other 2 are 2 cycle per instruction. That's 8 cycles. You even call nop twice in a row..
- You never increment *r6* in your *wait* loop, you never use the *str* instruction to update the cycle count. This means that according to your code, you can't even leave the *wait* loop because nothing ever changes.

According to your logic analyzer you do leave the loop, which you shouldn't be able to. This means that either:

- This question is a joke and haha, nice joke.
- Or there is an interrupt in the background changing r6 or the cycle count, and you don't know about it.
- Or you know about it and decided to not share it with us.
- Or the watchdog timer is kicking in and getting you out of the loop.
- Or this is not your actual code.
- Or the CMP instruction is backwards and you are leaving instantly which is shown in your first logic analyzer graph, then the STM becomes sentient and understands that you want a square wave and makes its best attempt and can only come up with a square wave with a period of 3.5 µs. Poor sentient being, it's just doing its best. I shall never forget you, you sentient STM being.
- Or I am just dumb.

---

If you want to make square waves with a period of 2 µs, then use proper timers. This means that during the time you are waiting, you can do other processes. If you want to count everything in loops, then you are effectively *freezing* the CPU, compared to using interrupts.

Since this will be interfaced with a *famous* Nintendo 64 controller, isn't there [some library](https://github.com/pothos/arduino-n64-controller-library) for this? Why look, there is one for Arduino.

My advice for you is to either:

- Port the library above from Arduino to STM32F429, or port [this](https://github.com/NicoHood/Nintendo) library.
- Put the STM32F429 in a box and use it when you need a 180 MHz microcontroller. Acquire an Arduino and use the library and call it a day, there's tons of arduino clones out there.
- Post your *actual* code in *text* format (not as an image).
- Research how to use interrupts on STM32F429.

Comment: Hey harry, thanks for the answer. Sorry that I completely omitted the fact that the above code uses the cycle counter. in the comment, some time back, I wrote "probably" because I had just taken that code from the disassembly. The cycle counter is initialized in the init section, and then `0xE0001004` contains the elapsed cycle count from then on.

Comment: I've also thought about using an arduino, I just wanted to work with what I had for now and not buy something new. I realize using an arduino might be easier.

Comment: I also don't just want to use an Arduino, because I'm doing this to learn about this stuff, not to interface with the controller ASAP :D

Comment: @fresskoma What you are trying to do sounds like taking a car to the bathroom. A little bit overkill and unnecessarily difficult and will most likely just handicap you. Just walk to the bathroom instead, solve it like a dummy with an Arduino. Or are you the kind of person who cuts his vegetables with a sword? And changes the channel on the TV with a pistol? Don't wipe with sandpaper. - In all seriousness, use the correct tool for any given problem.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I do appreciate you making it. I'd also like to note, though, that for someone who's never cut a vegetable before, the right tool might not be obvious. In addition, for someone who wants to learn to cut vegetables, telling them to "just employ someone who already knows cutting vegetables" also doesn't particularly help :)

Comment: Your cycles calculation is useless. The nop instructions are flushed away during the early pipiline stages. This trivial calculations are wrong and useless.  You do not take flash latency into consideration as well. To archive delays it is better to use the FPU instructions for example vsqrt. It takes IAS I remember 14 cycles, is not flushed from the pipeline, the micro has enough time to decide the next instructions removing the cache latency problem

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Oh, it's [you, again](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323411/the-nucleo-f411re-works-with-float-point/323413#comment755924_323413). Hello, and good bye.